# Firebase "update" operation downloads data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I was profiling a "download leak" in my firebase database (I'm using JavaScript SDK/firebase functions Node.js) and finally narrowed down to the "update" function which surprisingly caused data download (which impacts billing in my case quite significantly - ~50% of the bill comes from this leak):

Firebase functions index.js:

```
exports.myTrigger = functions.database.ref("some/data/path").onWrite((data, context) => {
    var dbRootRef = data.after.ref.root;
    return dbRootRef.child("/user/gCapeUausrUSDRqZH8tPzcrqnF42/wr").update({field1:"val1", field2:"val2"})
}
```

This function generates downloads at "/user/gCapeUausrUSDRqZH8tPzcrqnF42/wr" node

If I change the paths to something like this:

```
exports.myTrigger = functions.database.ref("some/data/path").onWrite((data, context) => {
    var dbRootRef = data.after.ref.root;
    return dbRootRef.child("/user/gCapeUausrUSDRqZH8tPzcrqnF42").update({"wr/field1":"val1", "wr/field2":"val2"})
}
```

It generates download at "/user/gCapeUausrUSDRqZH8tPzcrqnF42" node.

Here is the results of `firebase database:profile`

[image]

How can I get rid of the download while updating data or reduce the usage since I only need to upload it?

Comment: How exactly did you come to the conclusion that an update function is causing "download" bandwidth?  I'm shocked that any of the code you're showing would cause egress from Realtime Database.

Comment: @DougStevenson - update the question - please have a look

Comment: Maybe it's the [SSL encryption overhead](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing): _There is a cost associated with the SSL encryption overhead necessary for secure connections. On average, this cost is approximately 3.5KB for the initial handshake_

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder - the problem is that this overhead is triggered like 1000 times in 5 minutes producing quite a big amount of data comparing to the real payload.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible in firebase cloudfunction trigger.

The `.onWrite((data, context)` has a `data` field, which is the complete `DataSnapshot`.
 And there is no way to configure not fetching its `val`.

Still, there are two things that you might do to help reduce the data cost:

1. Watch a smaller set for trigger. e.g. `functions.database.ref("some/data/path")` vs `("some")`.
2. Use more specific hook. i.e. `onCreate()` and `onUpdate()` vs `onWrite()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please note that the problem is not in "onWrite" but in .update - if I for example return null in the "onWrite", there is no leak.

Answer (score 0):

You should expect that all operations will round trip with your client code.  Otherwise, how would the client know when the work is complete?  It's going to take some space to express that.  The screenshot you're showing (which is very tiny and hard to read - consider copying the text directly into your question) indicates a very small amount of download data.

To get a better sense of what the real cost is, run multiple tests and see if that tiny cost is itself actually just part of the one-time handshake between the client and server when the connection is established.  That cost might not be an issue as your function code maintains a persistent connection over time as the Cloud Functions instance is reused.

Comment: Thanks Doug - the problem is that the amount of downloaded data is as high as 300-400kb in most cases  (which is quickly becoming megabytes and growing)  and which is on average 10x more then the uploaded data itself. And it's actually triggered every time the function is called - this is when I actually noticed the issue

Comment: If you're concerned about billing, you should contact Firebase support to get a disposition.  Stack Overflow probably won't help you.  All I can say is that sockets are two-way connections, and what you've shown in your screenshot is a very small amount of data for a single operation, which is reasonable to expect.

Comment: Thanks Doug - I concerned about the fact that this operation takes too much of a data comparing to the real data I upload/download. This particular screenshot might not reflect the issue but it's still there. In general when my users are using the app, firebase downloads about 100mb a day and 50mb comes from this particular function which I don't expect. So I'm trying to understand how this "update" works and if there is any way to improve that. Firebase asks to post questions like this here actually. But thanks again for your input.

Comment: As I mentioned before, please contact Firebase email support with your specific concerns.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions that can be answered by the community at large. If you have concerns about how your data is being metered for billing, that's not appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks. My question is how "update" works so I can use it correctly - the bill just triggered this question. And from your response I understand that this is expected what I show here, correct? Btw, updated the screenshot in case it may give additional perspective.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can expect that any database operation requires a round trip between the client and server, so that the client can receive the result of the operation, even if it's just to say that the write was successful.

Comment: Ok thanks. So as per my screenshot, 77kB on average is still fall into expected roundtrip payload amount? Sorry for begging with questions, just want to make sure this all looks correct as I'm still a bit off track with this amount - also updated screenshot to include downloaded vs uploaded which shows that it downloads like 350x of the uploaded amount